# Where did EraNames go in Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

The unit SysUtils (System.SysUtils) no longer has an `EraNames` or `FormatSettings.EraNames`. What is its replacement and where did it go?

i.e:

```
 for I := Low(SysUtils.EraNames) to High(SysUtils.EraNames) do
    begin
      ..
    end;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because  I thought this might help someone.

Use `FormatSettings.EraInfo[x].EraName` and other properties of the EraInfo record.

The FormatSettings now holds an Array of EraInfo Records.

The for loop could be written:

```
   for I := Low(FormatSettings.EraInfo) to High(FormatSettings.EraInfo) do
   begin
     ...
   end;
```

Comment: And what about `EraYearOffsets`?

Comment: FormatSettings.GetEraYearOffset(FormatSettings.EraInfo[I].EraName)